# How to deal with dynamic input text elements on server side using servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

I have location table with location_id and location_name column in database and using this table I am showing input fields on UI. If there are 5 records in location table then 5 input fields will be rendering in UI.

Problem I am facing is:

Edit locations on UI and that changes should be persisted in db. Number of appearing input fields will be decided on the fly.

```
<c:forEach var="technologyLocation" items="${model.technologyLocationList}">
    <input type="text" name="location" value="${technologyLocation.location}">
</c:forEach>
```

Traditional way for updating is get updated request parameter value in server side and persist it in db. But, how can I achieve it when all input fields will be dynamic or any other approach? I am working with spring MVC. Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving all inputs the same name, so they get mapped into same variable and overwrite each other.

If you do it this way:

```
<c:forEach var="technologyLocation" items="${model.technologyLocationList}"
           varStatus="status">
  <input type="text" name="location[${status.index}]"
         value="${technologyLocation.location}" />
</c:forEach>
```

You will get `<input>` tags with name attributes `location[0]`, `location[1]` and so on in your HTML. Spring will automatically map them into a `List`.

[Here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/)'s a tutorial with more explanations.